# extract text between two words in a TEXT field

Tags: mysql

I need to fetch the text (regardless of content) between the first appearance of each of two words in a TEXT field.

The words will be set as variables at the beginning of the Mysql Script by the user and may change each execution.

```
SET @begin = 'DOLOR';
SET @end = 'AETERNAM';
```

On the mock text below,

```
 lorem ipsum DOLOR sit amet requiem in AETERNAM domine eis kyrie eleison.
```

I would like to be able to fetch `sit amet requiem in` without trailing or leading spaces.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @begin = 'DOLOR';
SET @end = 'AETERNAM';
SELECT       
   TRIM(SUBSTRING(
                     input,
                     (LOCATE(@begin,input)+LENGTH(@begin)),
                     (LOCATE(@end,input)-LOCATE(@begin,input)-LENGTH(@begin))
                 ))
   AS textbetween
FROM (SELECT 'lorem ipsum DOLOR sit amet requiem in AETERNAM domine eis kyrie eleison.' AS input) subq;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with nested calls to `substring_index()`:

```
select substring_index(substring_index(mock, @begin, 2), @end, 1)
```

EDIT:

You could also do this as:

```
select substring_index(substring_index(mock, @end, 1), @begin, 2)
```

The logic (for the first version) is:  use `@begin` to divide the string into pieces based on `@begin`.  You want the *second* piece (after `@begin`).  Then take the first piece, before `@end`.

I realize that both of these suffer a problem if `@begin` appears multiple times before the `@end` (which fortunately is not mentioned in the question).  If this can occur, then `substring_index()` is not the best approach.

Comment: i think you meant `substring_index(substring_index(mock, @end, 1), @start, 1)`

Comment: @Stephan . . . Your version would take the part of the string before `@begin`.   See the edit.

Comment: ur right BUT ur first ver is still not correct... pls exec these to check `SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(  ' lorem ipsum DOLOR sit amet requiem in AETERNAM domine eis kyrie eleison.',  'DOLOR', 2 ) , 'AETERNAM', 1 ) 
UNION 
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(  ' lorem ipsum DOLOR sit amet requiem in AETERNAM domine eis kyrie eleison.',  'AETERNAM', 1 ) , 'DOLOR', -1 )` BTW sqlfiddle is down